# php mysql select like not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

I am trying to query a mysql table using some "likes". But it doesn't work at all.

This is my code:

```
 $color_base1 = $row[color_base1];
$color_base2 = $row[color_base2];

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE (color_base1 LIKE 
           '%$color_base1%' OR color_base2 LIKE '%$color_base1%' OR color_base1 
           LIKE '%$color_base2%' OR color_base2 LIKE '%$color_base2%') 
           AND id_item != $itemId");

if (mysql_fetch_array($result2) == 0)
{
     $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE (keywords LIKE 
                '%$keywords%') AND id_item != $itemId LIMIT 3");
}
else 
{
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    echo "<div class='similarTitle'>YOU MAY ALSO LIKE</div>";
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
       echo "<div class='similarItems'>";
       echo "<img class='similarImage' src='images/{$row2[thumb1]}.jpg'>";
       echo "<div class='similarItemsText'>".$row2[name]."</div></div>";
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are not doing any error checking after your queries. Please add proper error checking as outlined in the examples in the manual `mysql_query()`

Comment: change mysql_fetch_array() to mysql_num_rows()? you have if(array()==0)

Comment: Echo your query and run it directly in database to know what exactly is the error?

Comment: Try and keep to one method of putting variables in strings ".$row2[name]." OR {$row2[thumb1]} I suggest the first as you can then ".htmlentities($row2[name])." or ".mysql_real_escape_string($keywords)."

Comment: Obligatory comment: Please don't write new code that uses the `mysql_*` functions. The extension is outdated and has been superceeded by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The PHP development team have begun the deprecation process for the stock mysql extension and it will be removed from PHP in a future version (hopefully the not-too-distant future).

Comment: Three answers, and *not one* teaches the OP how to debug this by themselves, and how to write good code. sigh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your queries into these:

Query1:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    item_descr 
WHERE   (color_base1 LIKE CONCAT('%' , $color_base1, '%') OR 
         color_base2 LIKE CONCAT('%' , $color_base1, '%') OR 
         color_base1 LIKE CONCAT('%' , $color_base2, '%') OR 
         color_base2 LIKE CONCAT('%' , $color_base2, '%')) AND 
         id_item != $itemId
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    item_descr 
WHERE   keywords LIKE CONCAT('%' , $keywords, '%') AND 
        id_item != $itemId 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$color_base1 = $row['color_base1']; // <- index NOT constant
$color_base2 = $row['color_base2'];

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE (color_base1 LIKE '%$color_base1%' OR color_base2 LIKE '%$color_base1%' OR color_base1 LIKE '%$color_base2%' OR color_base2 LIKE '%$color_base2%') AND id_item != $itemId");

if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0) // <- check for NO RESULTS
{
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE (keywords LIKE '%$keywords%') AND id_item != $itemId LIMIT 3");
}

$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
echo "<div class='similarTitle'>YOU MAY ALSO LIKE</div>";
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
```

1. Your array referencing is done incorrectly. $row['color_base1'] is not the same as $row[color_base1]
2. Your code gets an array from the search results (first row) and checks it against 0. I believe you mean to check the number of results returned and if there were none then check for suggestions.
3. If your second query is executed, it does nothing with the results
4. When you process your results to produce output, you are looping through the results from row 2 onwards (see point 2)

DEBUG:

1. if you do $sql="..."; then you can debug by echo-ing $sql and then checking the results manually by putting them into phpmyadmin
2. do lots of echo "I am at line:".__ LINE __; to check which path your logic is going in.
3. compare your phpmyadmin results with a var_dump($row); inside your loop to see if your skipping rows.
4. myql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); // will stop if your query is bad

etc.....

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your variables inside the query

```
mysql_query("select ... like '%" . $var . "%' ...");
```